# Laravel route setting incorret and search function issues

Tags: php, html, laravel

This function search user from MySQL. Can anyone knows which part I did wrong ?, `searchUser` function is not triggered.

admin view

```
<form type="get" action="role-permission-search">
    <input type="search" class="" name="query" placeholder="Search"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">search</button>
</form>
```

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>['isAdmin','auth']], function(){

    // Serch users
    Route::get('role-permission-search', [AdminController::class, 'searchUsers']);

});
```

```
    function searchUsers()
    {
        dd('Where are you');

        $search_request = $_GET['query'];
        $users = User::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_request.'%')-get();

        return view('dashboards.admins.rolePermission', compact('users'));
    }
```

Comment: if the button is not doing anything try using `type="submit"` for the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove type="button" from below line

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">search</button>
```

or change type="submit"

If still that not works for you then you should defile action="{{ route('YOUR ROUTE NAME') }}" in  tag